# How do I pull key words (not most frequent words) out of a corpus using Python and NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I am trying to pull key words out of a text or corpus.  These are not the most frequent words, but the words which are most "about" the text. I have a comparison example and the list I'm generating is very different from the example list.  Could you please give me a pointer to generating a good list of key words which doesn't include low-meaning words like "thou" and "tis"?

I'm using "Romeo and Juliet" as my text. My approach (see Scott & Tribble below) is to compare R&J with Shakespeare's complete plays, and to pull out words with occur significantly more often in R&J compared to the complete plays.  That should weed out frequent words like "the", but in my code it doesn't.

I'm getting lots of words like "thou", "she", and "tis" which don't show up on their list, and I'm NOT getting words like "banished" and "churchyard".  I am getting "romeo", "juliet", "capulet", and "nurse" so I'm at least close to on the right track if not actually on it.

Here's the function which pulls words and percentages out of the texts:

```
def keywords(corpus, threshold=0):
    """ generates a list of possible keywords and the percentage of 
           occurrences.
          corpus (list): text or collection of texts
          threshold (int): min # of occurrences of word in corpus                    
              target text has threshold 3, ref corp has 0
          return percentKW: list of tuples (word, percent)                         
    """

    # get freqDist of corpus as dict. key is word, value = # occurences
    fdist = FreqDist(corpus)
    n = len(corpus)

    # create list of tuple of w meeting threshold & sort w/most common first
    t = [(k, v) for k, v in fdist.items() if v >= threshold]
    t = sorted(t, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)

    # calculate number of total tokens
    n = len(corpus)

    # return list of tuples (word, percent word is of total tokens)
    percentKW =[(k, '%.2f'%(100*(v/n))) for k, v in t]
    return percentKW
```

Here's the crucial part of the calling code. targetKW is R&J, and refcorpKWDict is the complete Shakespeare plays.

```
# iterate through text list of tuples
for w, p in targetKW:
    # for each word, store the percent in KWList
    targetPerc = float(p)
    refcorpPerc = float(refcorpKWDict.get(w, 0))
    # if % in text > % in reference corpus
    if (refcorpPerc or refcorpPerc == 0) and (targetPerc > refcorpPerc):
        diff = float('%.2f'%(targetPerc - refcorpPerc))
        # save result to KWList
        KWList.append((w, targetPerc, refcorpPerc, diff))
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Normalized all potential key words to lower case (helped)
- Created custom short lists of key words (text and comparison text).  Seems to work but doesn't tell me anything
- Compared R&J to abridged list of plays, to plays + sonnets, and to Brown corpus (didn't help)
- Checked percentages of potential key words such as "banished".  Percents were a lot lower than expected.  I'm not sure how to interpret that.
- Set minimum length of potential key words to eliminate words such as "ll" and "is" (helped)
- Googled the question. (couldn't find anything)

I'm working with Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10 using IDLE version 3.5.2.

Source:
In "Natural language processing with Python" (http://www.nltk.org/book/), exercise 4.24 is "Read up on 'keyword linkage' (chapter 5 of (Scott & Tribble, 2006)). Extract keywords from NLTK's Shakespeare Corpus and using the NetworkX package, plot keyword linkage networks."  I am working through this book on my own for professional development at work.  The 2006 book referenced is "Textual patterns: key words and corpus analysis in language education" (especially p.58-60)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was already brushing up on TF-IDF for a project I'm working on so here we go. Basically no need for Pandas or Numpy functions in the code itself, though solidly recommend Pandas as I use it as my go-to for managing data. You'll need Scikit Learn for the TFIDF vectorization. If you haven't already got it, you'll need to [install it first](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html). Looks like just using `pip install scikit-learn[alldeps]` should do the trick but personally I use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which has it all pre-installed so I've not dealt with that side of things. I've broken down the process of finding the significant terms in Romeo and Juliet step by step. There are more steps than necessary to also explain what each object is below, but the full code with just the necessary steps is at the bottom.

## Step-by-Step

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Two sets of documents
# plays_corpus contains all documents in your corpus *including Romeo and Juliet*
plays_corpus = ['This is Romeo and Juliet','this is another play','and another','and one more']

#romeo is a list that contains *just* the text for Romeo and Juliet
romeo = [plays_corpus[0]] # must be in a list even if only one object

# Initialise your TFIDF Vectorizer object
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

# Now create a model by fitting the vectorizer to your main plays corpus. This is essentially an array of TFIDF scores.
model =  tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(plays_corpus)
```

If you're curious, this is what the array looks like. Each row represents a document in your corpus, whilst each column is each unique term in alphabetical order. In this case the rows run across two lines, and the terms are ['and', 'another', 'is', 'juliet', 'more', 'one', 'play', 'romeo', 'this'].

```
tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(plays_corpus).toarray()
array([[ 0.33406745,  0.        ,  0.41263976,  0.52338122,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.52338122,  0.41263976],
       [ 0.        ,  0.46580855,  0.46580855,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.59081908,  0.        ,  0.46580855],
       [ 0.62922751,  0.77722116,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.41137791,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.64450299,
         0.64450299,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Next we create a list of all the unique `terms` (which is how I knew the unique terms above).

```
terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

So now we have our main model of tfidf scores, which separately scores each term, in each document relative to its significance within its immediate context (the document) and its larger context (the corpus).

To find out what the scores are for the terms specifically in Romeo and Juliet we now `.transform` that document using our model.

```
romeo_scored = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(romeo) # note .transform NOT .fit_transform
```

This again creates an array, but one with only one row (because only one doc).

```
romeo_scored.toarray()
array([[ 0.33406745,  0.        ,  0.41263976,  0.52338122,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.52338122,  0.41263976]])
```

We can easily transform this array into a list of scores

```
# we first view the object as an array, 
# then flatten it as the array is currently like a list in a list.
# Then we transform that array object into a simple list object.
scores = romeo_scored.toarray().flatten().tolist()
```

Now we have a list of terms in the model, and a list of scores for each term, specific for Romeo and Juliet. These usefully are in the same order as well meaning we can put them together into a list of tuples.

```
data = list(zip(terms,scores)

# Which looks like
[('and', 0.3340674500232949),
 ('another', 0.0),
 ('is', 0.41263976171812644),
 ('juliet', 0.5233812152405496),
 ('more', 0.0),
 ('one', 0.0),
 ('play', 0.0),
 ('romeo', 0.5233812152405496),
 ('this', 0.41263976171812644)]
```

Now we just need to sort it by score to get the top items

```
# Here we sort the data using 'sorted',
# we choose to provide a sort key,
# our key is lambda x: x[1]
# x refers to the object we're processing (data)
# and [1] specifies the second part of the tuple - the score.
# x[0] would sort by the first part - the term.
# reverse = True switches from Ascending to Descending order.

sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
```

Which finally, after all that gives us...

```
[('juliet', 0.5233812152405496),
 ('romeo', 0.5233812152405496),
 ('is', 0.41263976171812644),
 ('this', 0.41263976171812644),
 ('and', 0.3340674500232949),
 ('another', 0.0),
 ('more', 0.0),
 ('one', 0.0),
 ('play', 0.0)]
```

Which you can limit to a top N of terms by slicing the list.

```
sorted_data[:3]
[('juliet', 0.5233812152405496),
 ('romeo', 0.5233812152405496),
 ('is', 0.41263976171812644)]
```

## Full Code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer,CountVectorizer

# Two sets of documents
# plays_corpus contains all documents in your corpus *including Romeo and Juliet*
plays_corpus = ['This is Romeo and Juliet','this is another play','and another','and one more']

#romeo is a list that contains *just* the text for Romeo and Juliet
romeo = [plays_corpus[0]] # must be in a list even if only one object

# Initialise your TFIDF Vectorizer object
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

# Now create a model by fitting the vectorizer to your main plays corpus, this creates an array of TFIDF scores
model = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(plays_corpus)

romeo_scored = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(romeo) # note - .fit() not .fit_transform

terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

scores = romeo_scored.toarray().flatten().tolist()

data = list(zip(terms,scores))

sorted_data = sorted(data,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)

sorted_data[:5]
```

Comment: Thanks again, James.  I see the top words in your code are "juliet", "romeo", "is", "this", "and", "another", "more", "one", and "play".  I'm actually getting more "about" key words from my code.  My top 9 are "romeo", "juliet", "thou", "capulet", "nurse", "and", "love", "friar", "lady", and "that" . However, also in my top 20 are "that", "thy", "she", "with", "thee", and "what". The code from the Scott & Tribble book doesn't have any generic words like these, and I can't figure out how they screened them out. Maybe I'm just being unrealistic in what I'm expecting from my code.  Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps tweak some options in the vectorizer, see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html. Perhaps you could come up with a list of stop words appropriate to the corpus and then feed that to the vectorizer. If not you can create a tokenizer function which filters the stops and then use that as a custom tokenizer instead of the built in one, that's another optional argument in the vectorizer. You may also find the ngram option useful, as it will include ngrams in the term list too. Finally try sublinear_tf=True to see if that helps.

Comment: @JenniferJames additionally `max_df` might be useful. Setting it to `max_df=0.3` for example would mean that any terms that appear in more than 30% of the docs in the corpus would be ignored.

Comment: Comparing the key words to a list of stop words worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible techniques that may be of use (and may go off course of the books) are Term Frequency Inverse Document Frequency (commonly TFIDF) weighting of words... and collocation.

TFIDF is used to determine what the significant words are within a document, in comparison to a larger corpus of similar documents. It's often used as a preliminary to machine learning for automated classification (sentiment analysis etc.)

TFIDF essentially looks at the entire corpus of plays, and assign a value to each instance of a word depending on how significant it was within each play, weighted for that term's significance in the entire corpus. So you would ideally 'fit' your TFIDF model to the entire corpus of Shakespeare plays (including Romeo and Juliet), and then 'Transform' Romeo and Juliet into an array of word scores. Then you find the highest scoring terms and these are the most significant to Romeo and Juliet, within the context of all Shakespeare's plays.

Some TFIDF guides I've found helpful...

https://buhrmann.github.io/tfidf-analysis.html

http://www.ultravioletanalytics.com/2016/11/18/tf-idf-basics-with-pandas-scikit-learn/

Collocation is available in NLTK and fairly easy to implement. Collocation looks for phrases, words that commonly occur together. These are also often useful for indicating what a text is 'about'.
http://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html

Happy to help with code if either technique is of interest.

Comment: Thanks, James.  I looked at both of these TFIDF guides, and it appears that to understand TFIDF I need to understand pandas, and to understand pandas I need to understand NumPy.  Is that true, or am I missing something?  If that's true, I'll take some time and try to learn them, as this looks like a really good solution.  I knew about collocations and was actually going to use them to create key word linkages further down in the exercise.

Comment: @JenniferJames Numpy and Pandas are great packages and worth learning. in fact you can just learn Pandas as it is layered on top of Numpy so it has the same functions, and I find it more accessible. However hopefully as you'll see in my other answer, you do not need to know either to do some basic TF-IDF scoring.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are too permissive in what you accept as a "keyword": Any word whose frequency is *even a little* bigger in your text than in the reference corpus will be treated as a keyword. Logically, this should net you about half the words that have no special status in the text.

```
if (refcorpPerc or refcorpPerc == 0) and (targetPerc > refcorpPerc):
    # accept it as a "key word"
```

To make the test more selective, choose a bigger threshold or use a smarter measure like the "out of rank measure" (google it), and/or rank your candidate keywords and keep just the top of the list, i.e. the ones with the biggest increase in relative frequency.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm putting the threshold test in the right place.  I'm currently looking at all the words of the target text ("Romeo and Juliet")  that occur more than n times in the text, where n is the threshold.  Is that where it's supposed to go?

Comment: The threshold I mean is the `>` comparison in the above snippet. _Any_ amount of difference, no matter how trivial, is enough to cause the target to be accepted as a key word. In other words, _this_ threshold is 0.